# Returning a customer from an arraylist of customers

Tags: java

So I have these two methods:
The first one is to go through the arraylist of customers and return a value `c` which is the customer whose ID of type `String` matches with one of the customers within the `ArrayList`.

```
private Customer findCustomer(String id){
    Customer c;
    for(Customer customer : customers){
        if(customer.getID().equals(id)){
            c = customer;
            return c;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then I have the second one which when someone access this method in my GUI of a make-shift movie rental program and passes in the movie, the day they are renting, and the id of the customer

```
public void movieRented(Movie m, Date rented, String id){
    m.setDateRented(rented);
    Customer c = findCustomer(id);
    c.addMovie(m);
    m.setIntStock(false);
}
```

I am getting an error message surrounding these two methods, and I just wanted to make sure that they at least look correct.

Comment: What error are you getting? And there is no use of that extra reference `c` in your first method. Just `return customer` instead.

Comment: please post the stack trace

Comment: You would get a `NullPointerException` at `c.addMovie(m);` if `findCustomer` returned `null` (not found).

Comment: Rather than iterating through an `ArrayList` in `findCustomer()`, you should check out a `HashMap`, which would allow you to store and look up all of your customers by id.

Comment: Always, *always,* **ALWAYS** tell us the **exact** error you are getting. That error, even if it makes no sense to you, is **very** important to help us diagnose and solve your problem. By the way, get used to quick responses on here: it's not too uncommon to be asked to edit something into your post 5 minutes after it's been asked. Please watch for that; without your exact error, we cannot solve your problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

Take care that you are returning null, so you can have a `NullPointerException`

```
private Customer findCustomer(String id){
        Customer c;
        for(Customer customer : customers){
            if(customer.getID().equals(id)){
                c = customer;
                return c;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

You may consider improving your method

```
private Customer findCustomer(String id){
            Customer c=null;
            for(Customer customer : customers){
                if(customer.getID().equals(id)){
                    c = customer;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return c;
}
```

Or better now , using custom exceptions

```
 private Customer findCustomer(String id) throws NoFoundCustomerException{
                Customer c=null;
                for(Customer customer : customers){
                    if(customer.getID().equals(id)){
                        c = customer;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(c == null){
                 throw new NoFoundCustomerException();
                }

                return c;
}
```

And in client code you can do something like this:

```
public void movieRented(Movie m, Date rented, String id){
    try{
    m.setDateRented(rented);
    Customer c = findCustomer(id);
    c.addMovie(m);
    m.setIntStock(false);
   }catch(NotFoundedCustomerException e){
     JOptionPane.showMessage(null,"Customer doesn't exist");
   }
}
```

And your exception would look like this

```
public class NotFoundedCustomerException extends Exception{

 public NotFoundedCustomerException(){
        super();
 }

 public NotFoundedCustomerException(String message){
        super(message);
 }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is right but there could be a spelling mistake in this line:

```
m.setIntStock(false);
```

It looks like is should be

```
m.setInStock(false);
```

It also seems that you could be having trouble if the customer is not found you return null. If you are not sure why this is happening I would suggest some simple println statements. For example:

```
System.out.println("customer id = " + customer.getId() + " id= " + id);
```